# data.table question: How not to overwrite the original data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

So with `dplyr` syntax when I e.g. use `mutate` I can wait until I like the result and start my data manipulations without an assignment and I can experiment. But it seems with `data.table` when I perform an operation I overwrite the original data frame and if I change my mind I have to reload the data and start over. When I use the pipe, I run the code often before the next pipe to see if everything is okay...

```r
library(data.table, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.6.1
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.1
df <- as.data.table(mtcars)

# dplyr version
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%  
  mutate(am = 2*am)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     2     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     2     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     2     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows

# here i will still have my original dataframe mtcars. 

df[, am := 2*am]
head(df)
#>     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  2    4    4
#> 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  2    4    4
#> 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  2    4    1
#> 4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

df[cyl ==6, am := 2*am]
head(df)
#>     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  4    4    4
#> 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  4    4    4
#> 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  2    4    1
#> 4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So here if I just want to add a filter with `data.table` I am going to multiply `am` with 2 again... is this how `data.table` works? Is there a way not to overwrite the data frame? Or should I always make a copy when I am afraid of making a mistake?

Comment: Try `df <- copy(mtcars)` as `:=` According to `help(":="), `DT is modified by reference and returned invisibly. If you require a copy, take a copy first (using DT2 = copy(DT)).`

Comment: The short anwsers are yes, yes and yes. But it is quite long to explain. Everything is well documented in this vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html

Comment: @JRR: So if I want to avoid updating by reference and assigning the result when I am ready then it is best to chain with ``DT[1:.N, ] [ , colA:=valA]`` and nothing will happen before I assign it, right?

Comment: @JRR: Or said in another way it is only when one uses ``:=`` in the *first* square bracket that modifying by reference happens, right? That is all i need to keep in mind... You agree?

Comment: The `:=` as been introduce to modify in place. If you don't want to modify in place just don't use it. Use `dplyr` or regular R idioms instead. In your example you chained a copy and a modification in place of the copy which is, in practice, equivalent to a modification with copy.

Comment: @akrun: can you please look at my questions 2 and 3 comments above?

Comment: @David I think it would create a copy of the object in the second case.  You can check the `tracemem` of both cases